# Colocar os dados que são digitados no input dentro de uma lista

Tags: python-3.x

Preciso armazenar os 10 números digitados pelo usuário em um lista, só que usando o "for".

```
for c in range(0, 10):
    s = int(input())
```

Então precisaria apenas saber como eu armazeno cada número após ser digitado e não só o último, como sei fazer atualmente.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro voce define uma array( s = [] ), em seguida utiliza a função append para inserir os dados digitados.

```
s = []
for c in range(0,10):
    s.append ( int(input()) )
```

Comment: Esse é o único uso dessa função ou ela tem outros usos?

Comment: o uso dela é apenas adicionar um elemento no final da lista

Answer (score 2):

O valor de inicio por defeito do `range` é `0` logo fazer `range(0,10)` corresponde a fazer `range(10)` que é mais simples.

Se apenas pretende fazer as leituras dos vários valores, pode faze-lo de uma forma pythonica utilizando [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) com:

```
numeros = [int(input()) for c in range(10)]
```

Que irá criar uma lista com os 10 valores que o usuário introduziu.

[Documentação para o `range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

Answer (score -2):

lista = []
for c in  range (0,10):
lista.append (int(input('digite 10 numeros para compor a lista')))
print('numeros escolhidos',lista)
soma_todos =sum(lista)
print ('A soma de todos os numeros da lista é:', soma_todos)